# Put/place in a state - synonym

Tags: synonyms

If I have a sentence:

> *Stimulus places/put me in a state of...*

Is there a neat synonym to *put/place in* in this case? Maybe I can rephrase it and use a different verb?

Comment: "...stimulus makes me..." (but you have to replace the "of noun" phrase with an adjective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance,

> This incident has put me in a state of paranoia.

Can be rephrased as

> This incident has made me paranoid.

Comment: It works, thank you. Though it's still not as 'pretty' as I'd like it to be. Probably there just isn't a way to phrase it as nicely as I would like.